# How to remove anchor tag with its text from the string in PHP

Tags: php

I have bellow string which has content and anchor tag:

```
$string = 'I am a lot of text with <a href="#">links in it</a>';
```

and I want to remove anchor tag with its text(links in it)

I have tried with `strip_tags` but it remains anchor text in the string, after that, I have tried with `preg_replace` with this example:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/i', '\1', $string);
```

but getting same result as `strip_tags`.

I just want "I am a lot of text with" after removing anchor tag.

Any idea?

Comment: If you know exactly from where to where in the string the anchor is located, you could just use `substr()`. Or do you not know that?

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2394254)

Comment: @Geshode It can be anywhere from the sting.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use `.*` wildcard inside `<a` and `a>`

```
$string = 'I am a lot of text with <a href="#">links in it</a>';
$string = preg_replace('/ <a.*a>/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

In case of multiple anchor occurence, you can use `.*?`. Making your pattern `'/ <a.*?a>/'`

Comment: `<a href="URL">Text</a   >` is also valid html, therefore your answer does not protect 100% agains xss

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it for **explode**. For your above example

```
$string = 'I am a lot of text with <a href="#">links in it</a>';
$string =explode("<a",$string);
echo $string[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `stristr()` for this([DEMO](https://eval.in/920906)):

```
<?php
$string = 'I am a lot of text with <a href="#">links in it</a> Lorem Ipsum';
//Get part before the <a
$stringBfr = stristr($string,'<a', true);
//get part after and along with </a>
$stringAftr = stristr($string,'</a>');
//Remove </a>
$stringAftr = str_replace('</a>', '', $stringAftr);
//concatenate the matched string.
$string = $stringBfr.$stringAftr;
var_dump($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
    function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

      preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
      $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

      if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
        if($invert == FALSE) { 
          return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 
        else { 
          return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 
      } 
      elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
        return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
      } 
      return $text; 
    } 

echo strip_tags_content('<a href="google.com">google.com</a>')

    ?>
```

Strip_tags_content is used to delete all tags along with it's content See the first comment of php manual [Strip Tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)